# Was the now dead Lior Sivan the IDF officer mocking demolished Palestinian homes?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

A [Reddit post on /r/Palestine](https://www.reddit.com/r/Palestine/comments/1bc67nd/lior_the_israeli_zionist_officer_who_was_mocking/) caption called,

> Lior, the israeli zionist officer who was mocking a Palestinian home getting demolished was killed today by the Palestinian resistance.

The picture attached is this one,

[image: picture perported to be Lior]

And that picture seems to be from [this viral video clip shared by Middle East Eye.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99TJNiafLh0)
A link inside the Reddit post to the [Syney Morning Herald has an article](https://www.smh.com.au/world/middle-east/australian-israeli-citizen-dies-fighting-in-gaza-20240102-p5eunw.html) that says,

> Lior Sivan, 32, died while serving as a tank commander on December 19, making him the first known Australian citizen serving in Israel’s defence forces to die in the Israel-Hamas war.

Along with a link to [a tweet by Stand With Us](https://twitter.com/StandWithUs/status/1737326697005920668) which has this picture.

[image]

While it seem reputable that a Captain Lior Sivan has died, is there any evidence this is the same guy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Likely Misattribution

The video by [Middle East Eye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99TJNiafLh0) is dated (in the video itself) as being December 21, 2023. While [ABC News Australia claims](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2024-01-02/australian-serving-with-israeli-army-killed-inside-gaza/103277994),

> Reserves Captain Lior Sivan, 32, was serving as a tank commander when he was killed on December 19.

This makes it impossible, unless it can be shown that the video of the IDF soldier mocking the demolished Palestinian home predates the express date on the Middle East Eye video, Captain Lior Sivan was dead 2 days prior that video.

Or, it may have been the last thing he did and the date may correspond to when Middle East Eye published the video, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 8):

No.

Captain Lior Sivan HID was an Armor officer. The soldier in the video is not an officer, as he doesn't have an officer's rank. And he is not a tanker, he is a military photographer. If it wasn't immediately evident by the camera and photography gear he is holding in his hand. He has a "Military photographer" patch on his shoulder.

From the video:

[image]

Examples for this can be seen on the [IDF Spokesperson's Unit Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDF_Spokesperson%27s_Unit)

[image: IDF Spokesperson's Unit military photographer]

Or from [this IDF Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/idfonline/photos/a.250335824989295/3451116091577903/?type=3):

> IDF combat photographers carry two weapons: a firearm to fulfill a dangerous mission and a camera to share the truth.

[image: picture of a photographer in full gear]

Showing and saying that IDF military photographers carry a weapon, just like in the video, in addition to their camera.

Just for reference, this is what an IDF Captain rank looks like on this type of uniforms in full gear (from left to right, Lieutenant, Lieutenant, Captain), notice the completely different color.

[image: Captain Dr. Harel] <sub>[source](https://www.ynet.co.il/laisha/article/rk2q7nrd6)</sub>